# Сортировка английских и русских слов в  NSArray

Tags: objective-c, сортировка

Нужно отсортировать массив так, чтобы сначала шли слова на Русском, а только потом на Английском.
Пробовал разные compare функции localizedCompare: localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare: localizedStandardCompare: и compare:options:range:locale: , не помогло. Подскажите пожалуйста, кто сталкивался

```
Пример:
@[Abc, Bcd, Абв, Def, Бвг]; - входящий массив
@[Абв, Бвг, Abc, Bcd, Def]; - то что нужно получить
```

Comment: Можно эту проблему решить иначе: после сортировки массива, определить индекс первого русского слова, разбить массив на английскую и русскую части по этому индексу и потом склеить их снова в нужном порядке.

Comment: Уточнение: слова могут содержать одновременно буквы и русского и английского языков? Если вдруг нашли своё решение, напишите его сюда в качестве ответа - было бы интересно взглянуть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если массив содержит только русские и английские слова, то можно создать 2 вспомогательные строки с английским и русским алфавитом. В сортировке брать первую по индексу букву из слова, приводить к нижнему регистру(если не нужно сортировать слова с большой и маленькой буквы), узнавать к какому языку она принадлежит и сравнивать слова между собой если они одного языка.

Вот так:

```
NSArray* words = @[@"Abc",@"Bcd",@"Grf",@"Влд",@"Гдр",@"Жзн",@"Hbr",@"Абв",@"Def",@"Бвг",@"Cdf",@"Acf",@"Aba"];

NSString* englishChar = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

NSString* russianChar = @"абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя";

NSArray* sortWords = [words sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString* obj1, NSString* obj2) {

    NSString* prefixObj1 = [[obj1 lowercaseString] substringToIndex:1];

    NSString* prefixObj2 = [[obj2 lowercaseString] substringToIndex:1];

    if ([englishChar containsString:prefixObj1]) {

        if ([englishChar containsString:prefixObj2]) {
            return [obj1 compare: obj2];
        } else {
            return 1;
        }

    } else if ([russianChar containsString:prefixObj1]) {

        if ([russianChar containsString:prefixObj2]) {
            return [obj1 compare: obj2];
        } else {
            return 0;
        }

    }

    return [obj1 compare: obj2];
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Столкнулся с похожей задачкой, решил ее на js, надеюсь, кому-то будет полезно.

```
var arr =["ФОРМАТЧИСЛО","formatNumber", "test", "лал","QWER"];
arr.sort((a: string, b: string) => {
                const temp = a.toLowerCase().trim();
                return temp.search(/[а-яё]/g) >= 0 ? -1 :
                    temp.search(/[\w]/g) >= 0 ? 1 : 0;
            });
```

Comment: не ясно, при чём тут javascript.